# LiipImagineBundle and BinaryFileResponse

Tags: symfony, liipimaginebundle

In my project i have some protected images outside the web root.

In my controller, i created a route that returns a `BinaryFileResponse` with the contents of the image i want to show:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/protected/images/{filename}", name="protected_image")
     */
    public function getProtectedimage($filename)
    {
        //.. logic ..
        return new BinaryFileResponse($path);
    }
```

In my template i use Twig's `path()` to render that route and show the image:

```
 <img src="{{ path('protected_image',{filename: myEntity.imagePath}) }}">
```

Now, i want to use that route together with `LiipImagine` to apply a `filter` and create thumbnails, like so:

```
<img src="{{ path('protected_image',{filename: myEntity.imagePath}) | imagine_filter('my_thumb_filter') }}">
```

The problem: always shows broken image and `Source image not found in ..` in logs.

Can i use `LiipImagine` together with a route that returns `BinaryFileResponse`? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could apply the filter before returning the response. This solution is not efficient however, because it applies the fitler on every request, so utilize the `CacheManager` in the bundle. (I'm still figuring out if it works for non-public images.)

```
/**
 * @Route("/protected/images/{filename}", name="protected_image")
 */
public function getProtectedimage($filename)
{
    //.. logic ..


    /** @var \Liip\ImagineBundle\Binary\Loader\FileSystemLoader $loader */
    $loader = $this->get('liip_imagine.binary.loader.filesystem');

    /** @var \Liip\ImagineBundle\Imagine\Filter\FilterManager $filterManager */
    $filterManager = $this->get('liip_imagine.filter.manager');

    $filteredImageBinary = $filterManager->applyFilter(
        $loader->find('path/to/image'),
        'my_thumb_filter'
    );

    return new Response($filteredImageBinary->getContent(), 200, array(
        'Content-Type' => $filteredImageBinary->getMimeType(),
    ));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is throwing a warning `Warning: is_file() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given`

Comment: Sorry my bad -`BinaryFileResponse` expects the path to the image, not the content itself. Instead use `Response` (answer updated).